# Minimal answer possible.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Are there a finite or infinite set of solutions that would satisfy this equation? If there are a finite set of solutions, what would it be? $$(2x+2y+z)/125\leq9.5$$ where $x$, $y$ and $z$ $\leq$ 250. Also $x$, $y$, and $z$, have to be integers.

Comment: $x,y,z$ positive as well? Integers? Clearly because you bounded your variables there will be a finite amount of solutions.

Comment: To prove that there are infinitely many you could build a representation of how to obtain them. Hint: when the $9.5$ was a  $10$ a while ago there were finitely many.

Comment: Yes they have to be positive. And well, yes that would make sense, it'd have to finite. How to find them is something I don't know.

Comment: @user16795 Are they integers?

Comment: Yes they are integers.

Comment: AH! I'm stupid. I copied my problem wrong. Of corse there isn't any... It's because it has to be less than or equal to 9.5 ... not equal to.

Answer (score 1):

There are an infinite amount of solutions.

First lets consider a part of your equation: $2x+2y$. The answer to this will always be a positive integer. Since 
$2*(+) = (+)$ 
and 
$2*(-) = (+).$
For conviniance, lets replace $2x+2y$ with $a$. so we now have $a = 2x+2y$

We can rewrite the original inequality as $a+z \leq 1187.5$

 now lets modifiy the question a bit more. Lets set $z=-a$
We can again rewrite the equation as this: $a + (-a) \leq 1187.5$
Now since $a \in \mathbb Z$ and $|\mathbb Z|=infinite$ there exist infinite solutions

Answer (score 0):

Let a = 250 - x, b = 250 - y, c = 250 - z when the equation becomes: 2(250 - a) + 2(250 - b) + 250 - c < 125(9.5) ===> 4a + 4b + 2c > -875/2 and a, b, c are now whole numbers. So if this condition was now in effect then there are infinitely many solutions.